# Sum of multiple dynamic columns

Tags: sum, asp-classic

I am using asp classic and sql. I can't sum up the multiple dynamic columns side by side. When the columns are stable, I can solve the problem like that "select sum (s1+s2+s3) as total" ... But my columns are dynamic. For example sometimes it can go on from s1 to s24 and sometimes from 1 to 13 .. etc. How can we solve this problem? My table are like this :

```js
w_id   | s1 | s2 | s3  | Total
-------+-------+-------+------
 1     | 4  | 3  | 5   | 
 2     | 0  | 5  | 10  |
 3     | 1  | 0  | 7   |
 4     | 5  | 6  | 0   |
```

I am very close to the result. But the loop doesn't work correctly. Where am I making a mistake? Would you help me in loop query? My codes are below.

`<%lastnumber=13%>`
`<%for x=1 to (lastnumber-1)%>`
`<% Next%>`
`<% dim a,b
a=objRec("s"&x&"")
b=objRec("s"&lastnumber&"")
%>`
`<%=a+b%>`

a=objRec("s"&x&"") this line doesn't work. It must be from s1 to s12. But ıt gives only s12.

Answer (score 0):

It gives only s12 because you loop to x=12 and nothing more:

```
lastnumber=13
for x=1 to (lastnumber-1)
Next

--> x=12 here

dim a,b
a=objRec("s"&x&"") --> x=12 here
b=objRec("s"&lastnumber&"") --> lastnumber=13 here

<%=a+b%> --> should be s12+s13 i.e. s12 because s13 does not exist
```

instead, you need to get each *s* in the loop, for example:

```
<%
dim total
total = 0
lastnumber=13
for x=1 to (lastnumber-1)
   total = total + objRec("s" & x)
Next
response.write "total=" & total
%>
```